# Values are not displaying on Flutter Charts

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, calendar

I am fetching data from firebase's real-time database to show in flutter charts but after function calling the value returned is still null/0. When getDuration() is called the data is shown inside the function but it is not returning. As I am new to Flutter, I don't understand the problem occurring.
If I hard code the values, then it shows on the chart but if I call function then it doesn't display bars.

My database looks like this:

[image]

I am fetching duration under the date to show inside the flutter chart on the y-axis with weekdays as the x-axis.

My code for flutter chart:

```
void initState() {
    getSeizureHistory();

    //Charts
    setState(() {
      var data = [
        addcharts(sevenDay.substring(0, 2), getDuration(seven),
            charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(const Color(0xffe8e5af))),
        addcharts(sixDay.substring(0, 2), getDuration(six),
            charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(const Color(0xffe8e5af))),
        addcharts(fiveDay.substring(0, 2), getDuration(five),
            charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(const Color(0xffe8e5af))),
        addcharts(fourDay.substring(0, 2), getDuration(four),
            charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(const Color(0xffe8e5af))),
        addcharts(threeDay.substring(0, 2), getDuration(three),
            charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(const Color(0xffe8e5af))),
        addcharts(twoDay.substring(0, 2), getDuration(two),
            charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(const Color(0xffe8e5af))),
        addcharts(oneDay.substring(0, 2), getDuration(one.toString()),
            charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(const Color(0xffe8e5af))),
      ];
      var series = [
        charts.Series(
          domainFn: (addcharts addcharts, _) => addcharts.weeks,
          measureFn: (addcharts addcharts, _) => addcharts.duration,
          colorFn: (addcharts addcharts, _) => addcharts.barColor,
          id: 'addcharts',
          data: data,
        ),
      ];
      chartdisplay = charts.BarChart(
        series,
        animationDuration: Duration(microseconds: 2000),
      );
    });
  }
```

getDuration() function:

```
int _duration = 0;
  int getDuration(String date) {
    //print("Date $date");
    //load the data from firebase and add to the list
    fb.reference()
      ..child(cuser.uid)
          .child('Seizure_history')
          .child(date)
          .once()
          .then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        var data = snapshot.value;
        list = List();
        if (data != null) {
          data.forEach((key, value) {
            EventList seizure_history = new EventList(
              seiz_duration: value['duration'],
              dateTime: value['datetime'],
              key: key,
            );
            list.add(seizure_history);
            setState(()
            {
              _duration = int.parse(list[0].seiz_duration);
            });
            print("Duration $_duration");
            return _duration;
          });
        }
      });

  }
```

Inside widget:

```
Center(
                    child: Container(
                        height: size.width * 0.80,
                        width: size.width * 0.90,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(11.0),
                        child: Card(
                          elevation: 5,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                          ),
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text(
                                  "Seizure Duration",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                    fontSize: 12,
                                    color: const Color(0xff232425),
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                  ),
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                ),
                                Expanded(
                                  child: chartdisplay,
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),),
                  ),
```

addcharts class:

```
class addcharts {
  final String weeks;
  final int duration;
  final charts.Color barColor;
  addcharts(this.weeks, this.duration, this.barColor);
}
```

On console, it is showing:
[image]

But on charts, it is still null:

[image]

Comment: Can you please point out where you called? `getDuration( )`?

Comment: Inside init state, I have used this function as argument in addcharts ()